# Django:Fetching values of single column

Tags: django, django-models

I have

```
 class holiday(models.Model):
   h_date=models.DateField()
   h_description=models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

when I query

```
 h_list=holiday.objects.all().values('h_date')
```

I get output as

```
 <QuerySet[{'h_date':datetime.date(2017,5,1)},{'h_date':datetime.date(2017,4,2)}]>
```

But I need output as

```
 2017-05-01
 2017-04-02
```

How can I get that output with just querying the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values()` method returns a `QuerySet` object. (BTW, you could use [dates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#dates), which directly evaluates to a list of `datetime.date` objects). You could use list comprehension to apply format though [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) method to each item:

```
[d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in holiday.objects.all().dates('h_date', 'day')]
```